# Using two Model class for a single adapter

Tags: android, listview

Im trying to have two model class for same adapter

This is what I do within getView method,

```
 ShipmentMasterDao item = (ShipmentMasterDao) listForView.get(position);
        ShipmentStatusDao statusDao = (ShipmentStatusDao) listForInflation.get(position);
        mViewHolder.mDate.setText(item.getStatus());
        mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(statusDao.getDate());
```

Both **ShipmentMasterDao** and **ShipmentStatusDao** are model classes.

Im getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaighai.model.ShipmentMasterDao cannot be cast to com.vaighai.model.ShipmentStatusDao
                               at com.vaighai.adapters.StatusAdapter.getView(StatusAdapter.java:81)
```

Following is my adapter code

```
public class StatusAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private View view;
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<ShipmentMasterDao> listForView;
    private ArrayList<ShipmentStatusDao> listForInflation;

    public StatusAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList list) {
        super();
        mContext = mContext;
        listForView = list;
        listForInflation = list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listForView.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listForView.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    //Viewholder class to contain inflated xml views
    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mstatus, mDate;
        private ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_progress, null);
            //ViewHolder object to contain myadapter.xml elements
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressIcon);
            mViewHolder.mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);

            view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        ShipmentMasterDao item = (ShipmentMasterDao) listForView.get(position);
        ShipmentStatusDao statusDao = (ShipmentStatusDao) listForInflation.get(position);
        mViewHolder.mDate.setText(item.getStatus());
        mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("adapter check");
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your total adapter class how exactly you are using..

Comment: instead of maintaining 2 separate models like this, why not just make a new model that has these 2 models as fields?

Comment: im not talking about server,  make a adapter viewmodel and put the dao and statusdao ad fields in that

Comment: Looks like your `listForInflation` is redundant: you get item from list (statusDao) but item is unused.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast your `ShipmentMasterDao` to `ShipmentStatusDao` here:

```
ShipmentStatusDao statusDao = (ShipmentStatusDao) listForInflation.get(position);
```

Your `listForInflation` full of `ShipmentMasterDao` items instead of `ShipmentStatusDao` I think.

**UPD**:
Error in constructor:

```
listForView = list;
listForInflation = list;
```

You should provide different lists for different models.
Maybe something like this:

```
public StatusAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ShipmentMasterDao> listForView, ArrayList<ShipmentStatusDao> listForInflation) {
    this.listForView = listForView;
    this.listForInflation = listForInflation;
```

Comment: i wish to use two different views within same adapter so I use two model classes.Is there any other ways through whIch i can do this?

Comment: how you are calling adapter class from activity class??you need to send two classes objects from your activity class and you just use those objects inside of **getview()** .

Comment: No, im calling is from onCreateView method.

Comment: any fixes available?

Comment: im trying to use one list view that has got two text views. The values of each textviews will be set with two different classes hance Im using two model classes

Comment: I guess you are looking for a generic adapter for multiple classes.

Answer (score -1):

pass second arraylist(listForInflation) to the constructor and try to use

```
public StatusAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList list, ArrayList list1) { 
    super(); 
    mContext = mContext; 
    listForView = list; 
    listForInflation = list1; 
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
```

}

You should call this adapter class from your activity class like following

```
StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(activity.this, list, list1);
```

**list** is for **listForView** and **list1** is for **listForInflation**

Comment: How about getCount, getItem methods? What should they return?

Comment: Both of the answers are correct. About `getCount` and `getItem` you need to let us know how you are using these lists. If one list item is related to one items from each list then you don't have to worry about anything. Just make sure you have same size list. Otherwise its little complicated.

Comment: one listview. each row has two different textViews. For setting values of those textviews, Im using model class

Comment: i think you have not created new object for arraylist classes.please check it once..

Comment: if you have created objects properly check the list objects having the same size or different size..